Kitchen Order of operations- tin & caulking
I have a couple “order of operations” questions regarding our kitchen we are upgrading.

We will be installing glue-on tin backsplash from American Tin Ceilings above 4in quartz backsplash up to the ceiling , the wall behind the stove,  and under the upper cabinets. Do I caulk the gap between quartz backsplash & wall and other similar gaps before or after the tin installation? (It’s similar to wallpaper but thicker)

We will be installing decorative wood trim around the cabinet edges —do I install the cabinet trim before the glue-on tin backsplash or after?



Do all the tin on the walls, then add your trim for the cabinets. The trim is to hide the uneven meeting between the cabinet and tin.  (It will be slightly uneven with the most accurate cut.It happens because the wall is not perfectly flat.)  Where possible, slip the tin behind any gaps in the backsplash or cabinets. It's not essential, but helps keep a cleaner line.
Caulk the backsplash to tin last. This must be sealed. Any water splashed will otherwise find it's way between the two and be an issue in the future.
